# Configure Nginx to serve static content conditionally based on the browser type

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have two static content bundles named "esc6" and "esc5" to serve both esc6 and esc5 supportive browsers. How should I write the nginx.conf file to conditionally switch the location directive based on the $http_user_agent value.

Ex pseudo code:

if $http_user_agent contains "chrome || firefox || safari" then esc6-bundle
else esc5-bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `map` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $bundle {
    default         /js/esc5-bundle.js;
    ~*Chrome        /js/esc6-bundle.js;
    ~*Firefox       /js/esc6-bundle.js;
    ~*Safari        /js/esc6-bundle.js;
}

server {
    ...
    location = /js/bundle.js {
        try_files $bundle =404;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Nginx  config

```
  location / {
      if (($http_user_agent ~ "Chrome") || $http_user_agent ~ "firefox" ) || {
          rewrite ^ esc6-bundle ;
      }
      rewrite ^ esc5-bundle ;
   }
```

Hope it help