# How to give one file to mobile phones and another to computers?

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

How to give one file to mobile phones and another to computers?

I have a Single Page Application, it works according to the principle: if the requested file exists, give it back, if there is no file, give it index.html

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I want to extend this behavior like this:

```
location / {
  if($mobile) {
    try_files $uri /mobile.html;
  }

  else {
    try_files $uri /desktop.html;
  }
}
```

How can this be done on nginx?

This not working:

```
location / {
  set $index_file desktop.html;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* "iphone") {
    set $index_file mobile.html; 
  }

  try_files $uri $index_file =404;
}
```

desktop.html rerturning to desktop, and reg exp works correct,
but if reg exp matched, $index_file variable takes on the value "mobile.html" i get error `403 Forbidden`

Comment: this not works too:

    set $index_file desktop.html;

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "iphone") {
      set $index_file mobile.html;
    }

    try_files $uri $index_file =404;

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790049/configure-nginx-to-serve-static-content-conditionally-based-on-the-browser-type/56790720#56790720). You need to use a leading `/` on all URIs. With a `map` you could use something like `try_files $uri $mapindex =404;`

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks you very much, worked. write your answer, I will choose the best one.